# Creating Post request in flutter and Laravel

Tags: laravel, flutter

[image]I'm creating a flutter app that authenticates the user using Laravel Api. User registration is working well but I'm getting the '_Exception (Exception: Not found)' on the Flutter code. Can someone help me what is wrong with my code.

Flutter code to register user:

```
 Future<User> register(name, email, password) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/register'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(
        <String, String>{
          'name': name,
          'email': email,
          'password': password,
        },
      ),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      // If the server did return a 201 CREATED response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      // print(response.body);
      return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 201 CREATED response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Not found');
    }
  }
```

Laravel controller method Api to register the user:

```
// user register function
public function register(Request $request){
    $fields = $request->validate([
        'name'=>'required|string',
        'email'=>'required|string|unique:users,email',
        'password'=>'required|string'
    ]);

    $user = User::create([
        'name'=>$fields['name'],
        'email'=>$fields['email'],
        'password'=>bcrypt($fields['password'])
    ]);

    $token = auth()->user()->createToken('myAppToken')->plainTextToken;

    return response([
        'name'=>$fields['name'],
        'email'=>$fields['email'],
        'password'=>$fields['password'],
        'token'=>$token
        ], 
    201);
}
```

Comment: try to print status code received from server .also check laravel log for any errors

Comment: The status code I'm returning from laravel is 201

Comment: A 201 is what your API returns if successful but yours is not returning a success response. So what is the value of the response status code and it’s message?

Comment: return response([
            'name' => $fields['name'],
            'email' => $fields['email'],
            'password' => $fields['password'],
            'token' => $token
        ], 201);

Comment: But still having the same error